# Spring -- load properties from file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, properties-file

Let's say I have in my `pom.xml` file a property

```
<webapp.base_url>http://localhost:8080</webapp.base_url>
```

And I also have a `webapp.properties` file that contains

```
base_url=${webapp.base_url}
login.block_threshold=100
```

I now want to read these property in Spring Boot:

```
PropertySource("classpath:/com/blahblah/myapp/webapp.properties")
@Configuration
class Configuration @Inject constructor(
    env: Environment
){
    init {
        Companion.env = env
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var env:Environment
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Configuration::class.java)

        val BASE_URL: URL by lazy { URL(env.getProperty("base_url")) }

        @Value("login.block_threshold")
        var BLOCK_THRESHOLD: Int? = null
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun logConfig() {
        LOG.info("Loaded webapp configuration:")
        LOG.info("BASE_URL                                  : {}", BASE_URL)
        LOG.info("BLOCK_THRESHOLD                           : {}", BLOCK_THRESHOLD)
    }
}
```

When logging the `BASE_URL`, I get a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webapp.base_url' in value "${webapp.base_url}"
```

Alright, Spring's trying to look up `${webapp.base_url}`, which means it's at least hitting the `webapp.properties` file.
Maybe I need to use `@ ... @` as I did with the `application.properties`?

```
base_url=@webapp.base_url@
```

Well, IntelliJ can now resolve it when I ctrl-hover over it, that's a good sign, right?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configuration': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: @webapp.base_url@
```

No, apparently it isn't.

And for the `BLOCK_THRESHOLD`, I get

```
BLOCK_THRESHOLD                           : null
```

Which is somewhat surprising seeing how `BASE_URL` at least resolved what was in the `.properties` file. So maybe I was too early ...

```
val INITIAL_BLOCK_THRESHOLD: Int by lazy {env.getProperty("login.block_threshold")!!.toInt()}
```

Yup, that one works ...

Is there a way to rewrite my `Configuration` class so that the `BASE_URL` property gets properly loaded from the `pom.xml` (and preferably so that  `BLOCK_THRESHOLD` is `@Value`-injectable, but that's not a priority)?

Comment: The @webapp.base_url@ will only be replaced if you do a maven build. So if you run the code nobody is replacing it.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Doh! Thanks a lot! Want to make an answer out of it? (Also, any idea why the `${}` aren't working? It's a legacy application we're migrating (from Thorntail to Spring Boot, if that matters), so in theory, it SHOULD work with them. (We aren't married to them, obviously, just curious.)

Comment: val INITIAL_BLOCK_THRESHOLD: Int by lazy {env.getProperty("login.block_threshold")!!.toInt()}

this was the only way that worked for me

Comment: the @Value in companion object probably does not work